# App Engine, How to check if all values in a list are in a string list in the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If you have a string list in the datastore that has the values:

a,b,c

How can you compare it against a list so that it only returns true if every value in the string list is present in the list?

['a', 'b'] would return false

['a', 'b', 'c'] would return true

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] would return true

Is this possible with GQL alone or would I need to pull put out the string list and loop over it?

Comment: You want to compare a list in a particular entity, or actually query for entities that contain the list?  A query will never return "true" or "false", so obviously as stated you can't do what you want in GQL.

Comment: @Wooble Query for entities that contain the list is what I meant. I realise a query won't return true or false, it was poor wording on my part.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringListProperty):

> A query cannot compare two list values. There is no way to test two lists for equality without testing each element for membership separately.

So I would guess that your comparison is also not possible directly.

It may be more efficient to use sets to compare, rather than looping over a list.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't directly possible. You can use multiple equality filters, and the query will only match entities that have at least those items in the list (eg, "WHERE foo = 'a' AND foo = 'b'" will only match if foo is a list containing at least 'a' and 'b'). If you do this without inequality filters or sort orders the datastore will use the built in merge-join strategy to satisfy your query.

Denormalization will provide more robust solutions, however. For example, if you serialize your list as a single string, you can simply check for equality with that string.

Comment: Would using several equality filters hurt performance? If I serialize the list as a string how would I check for equality when the string has additional letters? e.g. 'a,b,c' being compared with 'a,b,c,d'

Comment: jond: queries using the merge-join strategy are indeed slower than those only needing a lookup in a single index, but they may be the only solution in your use case, since being able to search for supersets will basically require you to use lists of possible subsets serialized as strings, which gets increasingly ugly as the size of your lists increases.

Comment: @jond I thought you wanted to search for entities that had the exact same list, not a superset?

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your list in a sorted fashion as a single StringProperty.  Depending on the content of your StringListProperty this may be as trivial as comma separated values.

Optionally you can use something like an md5 checksums to reduce the length of the string being stored and filtered against.